# Relationship between arctan2, arcsin, and arccos

Tags: trigonometry

I believe the reason for using `atan2` in most computational settings is due to the fact that it returns an unambiguous value for a given input. How does `atan2` relate to the other inverse trig functions, namely `asin` and `acos`? How can I convert between the operations?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 1):

`atan2(y,x)` is supposed to be the angle of the complex number $\arg\{x + iy\}$ and is supposed to be correct for all quadrants.  setting $$\arg\{x+iy\} = \arctan\left(\tfrac{y}{x}\right)$$ is correct only if $x>0$.

about the other relationships of the inverse trig functions, these are in books and [tables of trig and inverse trig identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Relationships_among_the_inverse_trigonometric_functions).